# How to reset terminal without losing the current command?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to create a keyboard shortcut to reset the current terminal.
I'm using a .inputrc entry like this:

```
"\C-K": 'echo -en "\\033c"\n'
```

It works, however, I can't do that while typing a command.

For instance, if I'm typing a command like this (with the cursor at the end):

```
$ foobar
```

and press CTRL+K, it will become

```
$ foobarecho -en "\033c""
```

and, of course, it is not going to work.
It is possible to do it?

I suppose it is possible, since that's what CTRL+L does.
The only problem with CTRL+L is that it won't clear the entire terminal, including history, just what's on screen.

Comment: Control+L calls a Readline function `clear-screen` which takes care restoring the current line after clearing the screen. One possibility is to bind Control-K to a macro consisting of Control-U (kill from the cursor position to the beginning of the line, your echo command, and Control-y (yank the previously killed text back to the current command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how to do that in `inputrc`, but you can do it with the `bind` command and its `-x` option.

```
bind -x '"\C-K": "echo -en \\033c"'
```

You can put the above line in your `.bashrc` and it will offer the same behaviour as the one you describe with CTRL+L.

Answer (score 0):

do not understand "reset the current terminal". Clean your terminal? If so you can use command **clear**

Comment: as far as i know, the `clear` command is to clear the terminal, the `reset` command is to reset the terminal

Comment: If you open a virtual terminal inside X, clear will clear the terminal, but the history will still be there. On the other hand, reset will wipe the history.